# Adding unknown number of values to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

My situation is that I am creating a wordpress plugin, it creates a table in the directory on activation.

This table holds information entered into the plugin, when information is being entered the user has the option to upload images. The number they will choose to upload I do not know.

The issue I am having is figuring out how to add these URLS into the database, sure I can just put them in there but again I do not know how many URLS need to be added.

As I cannot use normalization with wordpress, how would I store the URLS in the DB. Say they upload 5 images but I do not have 5 separate columns (URL 1, URL 2...)

I should also note that these images will be fetched using a for loop, so each image will be sent off regardless of the number they are uploading.

Any help would be appreciated
Cheers.

Comment: I don't know much about WordPress, but couldn't you just store the urls in a delimited field?

Comment: use 
post_id url
post_id url
post_id url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, You can make additional table with:

`id, information_id, filename, ordr`

Firstly, insert into infromation_table, get last inserted ID

Then, insert into filenames_table all your filenames in order

Finally, you can select data:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, GROUP_CONCAT(a.filename ORDER BY a.ordr ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS filenames 
FROM information_table AS i 
JOIN filenames_table AS a ON (a.information_id = i.id)
```

Comment: I did do a slight variation of this. I saved the information in JavaScript as a cookie as it was coming from Jquery then later accessed in PHP.

Comment: These cookies where named unique name (Uploaded_Image 0) then I accessed them in PHP and saved them to a separate table, that acts like a joining table without the constraints. 

Then I could query that table to see all images related to that ID.
Pulled them out and outputted URL in img src tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all image urls or other data into one DB row, you must create an array with all the information that you need, and then using `serialize` you can put this array in one filed in the database.

This filed must be `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT` to be able to collect all this information.

Then, when you get data back, you must use `unserialize` and data will be converted to arrays again if needed.

This is how WP stores information in the `postmeta` table.

Note that in this way you cannot easily query the data, so if this is important to you maybe will be better to store each image on separate row.